# Javascript onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This is a simple code, and it works in Chrome developer tool console, but when added onclick in html. It doesn't seem to work anymore.

Javascript:

```
function clear(){
  var display = document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].
                getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0];
  $(display)[0].innerHTML ="0";
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="clear-btn">
        <span> C </span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where is the `onclick` ?

Comment: Where is the `onclick` you speak of?

Comment: sorry, left that out. Can't seem to add the updated code in html format.

Comment: <div class="clear-btn">
                <span onclick="clear()"> C </span>
              </div>
              <div class="display">
                <span> HELLO! </span>
              </div>
            </div>

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What errors do you get? What's `$`? Are you using jQuery or some other library?

Comment: @j08691. the innerHTML doesn't get changed with the code. Whereas if I add the function in chrome console, and then execute clear();. It works fine.

Comment: @blackmamba24 You have jQuery included in your page?

Answer (score -1):

you fogot to add a trigger, to an element: `<span onClick="clear()">your text</span>`

Or you can add eventListener

Comment: Thanks very much, guys. The problem is that I used 'clear', which is reserved keyword. Much appreciated.